# Android Hybrid App - Chrome inspect Xpath unable to find using Java

Tags: android, xpath

I'm very new to Android Application Testing.
I started testing on a Hybrid Apps , After login page I want to capture few xpath and values of some specific elements.
I used chrome inspector to find xpath of few elements. When I used the same xpath in my java code it's not finding it. Size of xpath is showing as Zero.

I have already used Thread.sleep , element wait. I'm using the same xpath which I got from chrome inspector - Copyxpath feature.

Please help me how to verify if any frame or layout present in the application. I have attached HTML and my code, Added my new screen shot.

[Updated Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk2Vf.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQyQS.png).com/mvG6s.png

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, and the assumption that the arrow points from the line of code that fails to the HTML code it is supposed to match-up with, you have an incorrect XPath.  It goes from **ion-side-menu-content** to **ion-tabs** which does not match the highlighted line in the HTML code which instead goes to **ion-header-bar**.

Comment: Hi Bill , Thanks for the clarification. However I tried with the xpath which I got from Chrome Inspect - Copy Xpath feature . Still It's not working. I have added a new screen shot for the same issue. Please help me.

Comment: Do a ctrl-F while in inspect mode, which will enable the search box.  Paste the xpath in there and see if it goes to the same element in the HTML code or not.  You can also "fine-tune" the xpath by slowly hovering the mouse over the HTML code and watching what element gets highlighted in the browser itself.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bill , I did the same - When I search with my defined Xpath it's showing in HTML page and highlighted in inspect window properly. I came to know this hybrid app need to convery into Webview app in order to capture the element. I will try to change into webview.